# Как сделать нормальную ссылку на файлы с русским названием?

Tags: python, django

Беру url изображения, которое залито на форму, но, если у неё русское название, то есть: изображение.png, картинка.jpg и прочее, то полный url изображения будет таким:
`/media/2021/07/08/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0.jpg`
Как можно преобразовать это в строку с нормальным названием?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так работает, так называемый [*URL quoting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting), так как в урле ничего не-ASCII не принимается, все преобразуются в вот такой причудливый вид.

Как вариант, это можно преобразовать с использованием [`urllib.parse.unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote('/media/2021/07/08/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0.jpg')
'/media/2021/07/08/горе_от_ума.jpg'
```